# BottomNavigationView showing items problem

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I use `BottomNavigationView` in my app (modified from sample project) and I want to change the items in the container. I have 4 items within the container, 5 including the BottomNavigationView. I only want to display 2 items when apps is first start. Then show another 2 items and hide the previous 2 items when one of the `Button` in `BottomNavigationView` is clicked.
[image]
How to do it?

Comment: do you want to hide the menu items in bottombar? OR the views in the layout based on the click event on bottombar

Comment: you said you had problem . What is the problem?

Comment: whats is the problem,share the code.

Comment: i want to hide the view in the layout base on the click event on bottom bar when apps first start. for instance, when app first start I just want to show the edit text and button item and hide the 2 textview.

Comment: The problem is I cannot put only 2 items (the edit text and the button) when apps first start. The 4 items always showed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to hide any view button,textview or edittext just use this code on the button click

```
view.setVisibility(GONE)
```

GONE hides the whole view even the height and the width of the view

```
view.setVisibility(INVISIBLE)
```

INVISIBLE only hides the content but preserves the height and the width

Comment: Ah yes, it works. First set the visibility attribute to GONE, then when a BottomNavigationView  button is pressed set visibility to Visible. Thank you...

Comment: happy to help!!

Answer (score 1):

```
  boolean state;  // define boolean variable



 home.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 info.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

In your botton navigation click listener just use

```
  b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if ( state )
            {
                state = false;
                home.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                info.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                state = true;
                home.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                info.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
```